# How to scroll a page, with image and gridView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, scrollview, scrollable

My code for the page is like this. I need to scroll part below app bar.

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
    title: Text(campTitle,
      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        
        ),
      ),
  ),

  body: Column(children: [
            Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40, top: 10),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/Flyer-Kalabrien-2020.jpg',
                      //fit: BoxFit.fill
                      
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
          

               Expanded(
                 child: GridView(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                    childAspectRatio: 1,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 0
                    ),
                    children: [
                        CampItems(),
                        CampItems(),
                        CampItems(),
                        CampItems()

                      
                      

                    ],
                  ),
               ),
            
      ]
   ), 
  );
```

I need to make the part below app bar scrollable. first I have an image and then below the image an GridView.I tried SingleChildScrollView and other widgets but then I only see a white screen and the error is:

```
_AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1785:12)
#3      RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:168:9)
#4      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2596:25)
#5      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:787:31)
#6      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2591:33)
#7      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:412:12)
#8      Rend<…>
```

Comment: see my answer, let me know if you have any question!

Comment: Use ListView instead of Column as body of scaffold, this way it helps you to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Expanded, try  shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ScrollPhysics(),

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`
- In Column, set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`
- Remove `Expanded` widget
- In `GridView` property, set `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`

Code:

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('campTitle'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40, top: 10),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
              child: Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 100, fallbackWidth: 100),
            ),
          ),
          GridView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 0),
            children: [
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
              Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: GridView is scrollable. I fail to see the point in wrapping it in a SingleChildScrollView?!

Comment: @YoBo Correct. Actually, it wrapped with the `Column` before being wrapped in `SingleChildScrollView`. We wrap with `SingleChildScrollView` to allows its children to become scrollable (not only the `GridView`)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and replace accordingly:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('campTitle'),
      ),
      body: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40, top: 10),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
            child: Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 100, fallbackWidth: 100),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible( // important to make it work
            child: GridView(
                physics: ScrollPhysics(), // also important to make your gridview scrollable
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                    childAspectRatio: 1,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 0),
                children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) // i is the number of your CampItems()
                Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30, fallbackWidth: 30), // replace with CampItems()

            ])),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

---

*For a full list of GridView properties, please refer to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)*

> **physics → ScrollPhysics**
> How the scroll view should respond to user input. [...]

> **shrinkWrap → bool**
> Whether the extent of the scroll view in the scrollDirection should be determined by the contents being viewed. [...]

---

You might also want to read about **[Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)** and **[Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)**

*About Flexible:*

> Using a Flexible widget gives a child of a Row, Column, or Flex the flexibility to expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column), but, unlike Expanded, Flexible does not require the child to fill the available space.

---

Also it is better to wrap Scaffold with [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)

> A widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system.